# What does conditioning on a random variable mean?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditioning

What does conditioning on a random variable mean?

For example: in p(X|Y), X and Y are the random variables, so does the conditioning on Y mean Y is fixed (or non-random)?

Comment: wondering what a conditional random variable means, normally a conditioned random variable means known value, such as P(X|Y=1), but I also noticed sometimes Y is unspecified as P(X|Y=y), so in this case, what does a condition really mean?

Comment: It can also be interpreted as filtering query before computing the probabilty, as in WHERE in sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the value of the random variable Y is known. For example, suppose $E(X|Y)=10+Y^2$. Then if $Y=2, ~E(X|Y=2)=14.$

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I found that E(X|Y=y) is also possible, so here the y is still unspecified and E(X|Y=y)=10+y^2, in this case, do the condition only remove the randomness of the Y?

Comment: $E(X|Y=y)$ is just a different notation. If you are conditioning on $Y$, that means $Y$ is known. $E(X|Y=y)=10+y^2$ is a function that gives expected value of $X$ conditional on $Y=y$ for an arbitrary value of $Y$.

Comment: my understanding is that if E(X|Y=y), the Y is still not a known value, but a non-random unknown variable,  which means the condition Y=y only removed the randomness of random variable Y. In summary, the conditioning random variable is either a specific value(like Y=5) or a unspecified non-random variable(like Y=y), but in either case, the Y is not treated as random anymore in terms of expectation of X. Am I right to think this way?

Comment: Yes, that's fair. Our different explanations our just semantics.

Answer (score 25):

Conditioning on a random variable is *much more subtle* than conditioning on an event.

## Conditioning on an Event

Recall that for an *event* $B$ with $P(B) > 0$ we define the *conditional probability given $B$* by
$$
P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}
$$
for every event $A$. This defines a new probability measure $P(\ \cdot\mid B)$ on the underlying probability space, and if $X$ is a random variable which is either non-negative or $P$-integrable on $A$, then we have
$$
E[X \mid B]
= \int X \, dP(\ \cdot\mid B)
= \frac{1}{P(B)} \int X \mathbf{1}_B \, dP.
$$
The intuitive interpretation is that $E[X \mid B]$ is the "best guess" for what value $X$ takes, knowing that the event $B$ actually happens.
This intuition is justified by the last integral above: we integrate $X$ with respect to $P$, but *only* on the event $B$ (and dividing by $P(B)$ is due to us concentrating all our attention on $B$ and hence re-weighting $B$ to have probability $1$).

That's the easy case. To understand conditioning on a random variable, we need the more general idea of conditioning on *information*. A probability measure by itself gives us *prior* probabilities for all possible events. But probabilities that certain events happen change if we know that certain other events do or do not happen. That is, when we have *information* about whether certain events happen or not, we can update our probabilities for the remaining events.

## Conditioning on a Collection of Events

Formally, suppose $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of events. Assume that it is known whether each event in $\mathcal{G}$ happens or not.
We want to define the conditional probability $P(\ \cdot\mid \mathcal{G})$ and the conditional expectation $E[\ \cdot\mid \mathcal{G}]$.
The conditional probability $P(A \mid \mathcal{G})$ should reflect our updated probability of an event $A$ after knowing the information contained in $\mathcal{G}$, and $E[X \mid\mathcal{G}]$ should be our "best guess" for the value of a random variable $X$ using the information contained in $\mathcal{G}$.

(NB: Why should $\mathcal{G}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra and not a more general collection of events? Because if $\mathcal{G}$ weren't a $\sigma$ algebra but we know whether each event in $\mathcal{G}$ happens or not, then we would know whether each event in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{G}$ happens or not, so we might as well replace $\mathcal{G}$ with $\sigma(\mathcal{G})$.)

### Conditional Probability

Here's where things get interesting. $P(A \mid\mathcal{G})$ is no longer just a number: it is a *random variable*!. We define $P(A \mid\mathcal{G})$ to be any $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable $X$ such that
$$
E[X \mathbf{1}_B] = P(A \cap B)
$$
for every event $B \in \mathcal{G}$.
Moreover, if $X$ and $X^\prime$ are two random variables satisfying this definition, then $X = X^\prime$ almost surely.
That is pretty abstract stuff, so hopefully an example can shed some light on the abstraction.

**Example**.
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, and let $B \in \mathcal{F}$ be an event with $0 < P(B) < 1$.
Suppose $\mathcal{G} = \{\emptyset, B, B^c, \Omega\}$.
That is, $\mathcal{G}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra containing all the information about whether $B$ happens or not.
Then for any event $A \in \mathcal{F}$ we have
$$
P(A \mid \mathcal{G})
= P(A \mid B) \mathbf{1}_B + P(A \mid B^c) \mathbf{1}_{B^c}.
$$
That is, for an outcome $\omega \in \Omega$, we have
$$
P(A \mid \mathcal{G})(\omega) = P(A \mid B)
$$
if $\omega \in B$ (i.e., if $B$ *happens*), and
$$
P(A \mid \mathcal{G})(\omega) = P(A \mid B^c)
$$
if $\omega \notin B$ (i.e., if $B$ doesn't happen).
It is easy to check that this random variable actually satisfies the definition of the conditional probability $P(A \mid \mathcal{G})$ defined above.

### Conditional Expectation

I mentioned already that conditional probabilities aren't unique, but they are unique almost surely.
It turns out that if $X$ is a nonnegative or integrable random variable, $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of events, and $Q$ is the distribution of $X$ (a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$) then it is possible to choose versions of conditional probabilities $Q(B \mid \mathcal{G})$ for all Borel subsets $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $Q(\ \cdot \mid \mathcal{G})(\omega)$ is a probability measure for each outcome $\omega$. Given this possibility, we may define
$$
E[X\mid\mathcal{G}]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, Q(dx\mid\mathcal{G}),
$$
which is again a *random variable*.
It can be shown that this is the almost surely unique random variable $Y$ which is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and satisfies
$$
E[Y \mathbf{1}_A] = E[X \mathbf{1}_A]
$$
for all $A \in \mathcal{G}$.

## Conditioning on a Random Variable

Given the general definitions of conditional probability and conditional expectation given above, we may easily define what it means to condition on a random variable $Y$: it means conditioning on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$:
$$
\sigma(Y)
= \big\{\{Y \in B\} : \text{$B$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$}\big\}.
$$
I said "easy to define," but I am aware that that doesn't mean "easy to understand."
But at least we can now say what an expression like $E[X \mid Y]$ means: it is a *random variable* that satisfies
$$
E[E[X \mid Y] \mathbf{1}_A] = E[X \mathbf{1}_A]
$$
for every event $A$ of the form $A = \{Y \in B\}$ for some Borel subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$.
Wow, that's abstract!
Fortunately, there are easy ways to work with $E[X \mid Y]$ if $Y$ is discrete or absolutely continuous.

### $Y$ Discrete

Suppose $Y$ takes values in a countable set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.
Then it can be shown that
$$
P(A \mid Y)(\omega) = P(A \mid Y = Y(\omega))
$$
for each outcome $\omega$.
The right-hand side above is shorthand for the more verbose
$$
P(A \mid \{Y = Y(\omega)\})
$$
where $\{Y = Y(\omega)\}$ is the event
$$
\{Y = Y(\omega)\}
= \{\omega^\prime : Y(\omega^\prime) = Y(\omega)\}.
$$
That is, if our outcome is $\omega$, and $Y(\omega) = k$, then
$$
P(A \mid Y)(\omega) = P(A \mid Y = k) = \frac{P(A \cap \{Y = k\})}{P(Y = k)}.
$$
Similarly, if $X$ is another random variable taking values in $S$, then we have
$$
E[X \mid Y](\omega) = E[X \mid Y = Y(\omega)] = \sum_{x \in S} x P(X = x \mid Y = Y(\omega))
$$

### $Y$ Absolutely Continuous

Suppose now that $Y$ is absolutely continuous with density $f_Y$.
Let $X$ be another absolutely continuous random variable, with density $f_X$.
Let $f_{X, Y}$ be the joint density of $X$ and $Y$.
Then we define the *conditional density* of $X$ given $Y = y$ by
$$
f_{X\mid Y}(x \mid y) = \frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{f_Y(y)}
= \frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X, Y}(x^\prime, y) \, dx^\prime}.
$$
Now we may define a function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
g(y)
= E[X \mid Y = y]
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} x f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y) \, dx.
$$
In particular, $g(y) = E[X \mid Y = y]$ is a *real number* for each $y$.
Using this $g$, we can show that
$$
E[X \mid Y] = g(Y),
$$
meaning that
$$
E[X \mid Y](\omega) = g(Y(\omega)) = E[X \mid Y = Y(\omega)]
$$
for each outcome $\omega$.

This is just scratching the surface of the theory of conditioning.
For a great reference, see chapters 21 and 23 of *A Modern Approach to Probability* by Fristedt and Gray.

> ## Some Takeaways
>
> 1. Conditioning on a random variable is different from conditioning on an event.
> 2. Expressions like $P(A \mid Y)$ and $E[X \mid Y]$ are *random variables*
> 3. Expressions like $P(A \mid Y = y)$ and $E[X \mid Y = y]$ are *real numbers*.

Comment: What is a sigma-algebra?

Comment: @ProQ please see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra) for details. In the context of probability, a sigma-algebra is a set of events that satisfies some useful properties. One way of intuiting about them is that a sigma-algebra is a way of capturing "information" about outcomes of a statistical experiment, but a detailed discussion of that is better suited for its own question (or there might be one here or on math.SE already!)

Answer (score 13):

Conditioning on an event (such as a particular specification of a random variable) means that this event is treated as being known to have occurred.  This still allows us to specify conditioning on an event $\{ Y=y \}$ where the actual value $y$ is an algebraic variable that falls within some range.$^\dagger$  For example, we might specify the conditional density:

$$p_{X|Y}(x|y) = p(X=x | Y=y) = {y \choose x} \frac{1}{2^y}
\quad \quad \quad \text{for all integers } 0 \leqslant x \leqslant y.$$

This refers to the probability density for the random variable $X$ conditional on the known event $\{ Y=y \}$, where we are free to set any $y \in \mathbb{N}$.  The use of the variable $y$ in this formulation simply means that the conditional distribution has a form that allows us to substitute a range of values for this variable, so we write it as a function of the conditioning value as well as the argument value for the random variable $X$.  Regardless of which particular value $y$ we choose, the resulting density is conditional on that event being treated as known ---i.e., no longer random.

As I have stated in another answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/374783/374785#374785), it is also worth noting that many theories of probability regard *all probability* to be conditional on implicit information.  This idea is most famously associated with the axiomatic approach of the mathematician Alfréd Rényi (see e.g., [Kaminski 1984](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm79/sm79115.pdf)).  Rényi argued that every probability measure must be interpreted as being conditional on some underlying information, and that reference to marginal probabilities was merely a reference to probability where the underlying conditions are implicit, rather than explicit.

---

$^\dagger$ Technically, it's worth noting that if we conditioning on the value of a continuous random variable (an event with probability zero) then there is an extended definition of the conditional probability.  Essentially this is just a function that satisfies the required integral statement for the marginal probability.  In the present answer we will stick to discrete random variables to keep things simple.

Comment: The expression for the conditional pdf should depend on x in some way, like $\phi(x-y)$.

Comment: Ben, would you be able to elaborate or send resources on the extended definition of the conditional probability for conditioning on the value of a continuous random variable, that satisfies the integral statement for the marginal probability?

Comment: @aesthete: I recommend you read about conditional probability in an advanced probability book such as [Billingsley (1995)](https://www.amazon.com.au/Probability-Measure-Patrick-Billingsley/dp/0471007102).